Distributed locks of file-backed mmap()-ed memory over network block devices
There are various ways to access block devices over a network, like

nbd, alias network block device
iscsi, alias scsi over tcp
or simply we can mmap() files mounted in an nfs or cifs network share.

I am now thinking about a process, mmap()-ing such block devices and then flock()-ing them or part of them. Obviously, as they are in a network share, such memory locks can happen concurrently on multiple devices.
What I am trying to do, is to distribute and handle these concurrent locks even across the network, i.e. if a lock happens on a node, it should affect also other nodes. It probably requires some RPC-based protocol, which is likely not trivial, but possible to develop.
Does such a thing exist?

NFS v4 supports flock natively (and fcntl locks worked even before that, I think. But that's only of archaelogical interest); using a file-based access scheme is anyways the only way to get file-based functionality such as locking.

It probably requires some RPC-based protocol, which is likely not trivial, but possible to develop.

"An RPC protocol that's not trivial but possible" is actually an interesting description of NFS. (Some, Tom Lyons included, might call it optimistic.) NFS is 100% an RPC system, with a lot of thought going into which state is held where.

Ok, but if I lock a file on node1, will it be locked also on node2? What if I do not lock with flock, instead I mmap() the file and then I lock the memory region in its address space?

yes, it will, that's the point.

Ok, I write a test-tool for that. Imho it could work and it should work, but... I feel the cloudy face expression of a coworker, asking with eyes wide open, why would it be needed. In the kernel internals, it would also mean that the very low-level memory locking call should be somehow hooked into a network operation, another huge complexity provider. I am surprised but also very happy if it was really implemented.

wait, I thought you were doing fcntl on the file descriptor that you mmap'ed? Am I mistaken?

The development is not yet in that stage :-) Looks I have a third question. Actually, locking should not happen with flock and neither with fcntl. I do not want to lock files. I want to lock memory pages. How does a multi-threaded process lock memory pages? I need blocking, mandatory locks.

(fcntl can lock regions in files, whether you mmap them or use them with read/write, and mandatory locks on files in Linux ceased to exist in Linux 5, because they were always a bit broken and nobody used that functionality, but:) Multi-threading and local memory locking has little to do with cross-network synchronization, so I'm not sure we're aiming at the right functionality here! But this sounds interesting, maybe really open a new question that describes what you want to do multi-threadedly and across multiple machines on a network :)
